# How to pass ${CTEST_CONFIGURATION_TYPE} using add_test in cmake

Tags: windows, cmake, ctest

I can't seem to figure out how to pass ${CTEST_CONFIGURATION_TYPE} using add_test in cmake without having CMake add additional escape characters.

I am currently using cmake to generate VS project files and setting the RUNTIME_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY and need to use this directory + configuration as the working directory for a few of the tests as they depend on other built executables.

I have tried using

```
add_test(NAME test 
     WORKING_DIRECTORY "${CMAKE_RUNTIME_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY}/\${CTEST_CONFIGURATION_TYPE}"
     COMMAND test ${TEST_ARGS})
```

This correctly finds my test executable, however the CTestTestfile.cmake file that is generated contains

```
WORKING_DIRECTORY "<CORRECT_RUNTIME_PATH>/\${CTEST_CONFIGURATION_TYPE}"
```

Is there anyway I can get this to work or am i just going to have to pass the correct directory to the test via command line every time?

Comment: To clarify, you want to pass a string that contains the literal _${CTEST_CONFIGURATION_TYPE}_, as opposed to CMake substituting it by the variable's content?

Comment: yes, that way the generated CTestTestfile.cmake contains the line set_tests_properties(test WORKING_DIRECTORY "<CORRECT_RUNTIME_PATH>/${CTEST_CONFIGURATION_TYPE}")

Answer (score 2):

This is currently impossible in the general case. In the next version of CMake, you should be able to use the feature in this [commit](http://cmake.org/gitweb?p=cmake.git;a=commitdiff;h=07934636) to use generator expressions in your test properties.

Comment: Good call. +1  Just to be clear, we're talking about this being available as of v2.8.12 I think.  Also, generator expressions have been available for a while in `add_test`; the difference now is that they can be used within the `WORKING_DIRECTORY` argument as well as the `COMMAND` argument.

Answer (score 1):

**Update:**

As @mathstuf has pointed out in his own [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18880007/2556117), as of version 2.8.12 CMake supports generator expressions within the `WORKING_DIRECTORY` argument of `add_test`.  This makes the rest of my answer only applicable to CMake v2.8.11 and below.

---

As far as I know, it's not really possible to pass a "$" through `ADD_TEST` without it ending up escaped in `CTestTestfile.cmake`.

Really the "CMake" way to handle this situation is probably to pass the dependent exes to the test exe as a command line parameter, which would involve changing the test code.  If the dependent executables are all CMake targets, they can be referenced in the `ADD_TEST` command using "`$<TARGET_FILE:tgt>`" where `tgt` is the name of the CMake target.

There is however a big, dirty hack you could use to get round this.  Replace your `ADD_TEST` command with:

```
ADD_TEST(NAME test WORKING_DIRECTORY "@WORKING_DIR@" COMMAND test ${TEST_ARGS})
FILE(WRITE ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/CTestCustom.cmake
     "SET(WORKING_DIR \"${CMAKE_RUNTIME_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY}/\\\${CTEST_CONFIGURATION_TYPE}\")\n")
FILE(APPEND ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/CTestCustom.cmake
     "CONFIGURE_FILE(${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/CTestTestfile.cmake ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/CTestTestfile.cmake @ONLY)\n")
```

This is (ab)using CTest's behaviour by creating a `CTestCustom.cmake` file which is invoked before the `CTestTestfile.cmake`.  After running CMake, `CTestTestfile.cmake` has the line

```
SET_TESTS_PROPERTIES(test PROPERTIES  WORKING_DIRECTORY "@WORKING_DIR@")
```

By running CTest and invoking `CTestCustom.cmake`, the `"@WORKING_DIR@"` is replaced with the correct value.

It really is a hack; messing with auto-generated CMake files is asking for trouble, but it could do until you get time to refactor your tests or CMake becomes better able to support a per-configuration `WORKING_DIRECTORY`.

Comment: Generator expressions in test properties are now on their way into CMake proper. This way you can do things as seen in the tests here: <http://cmake.org/gitweb?p=cmake.git;a=commitdiff;h=07934636>

Comment: @mathstuf your provided git link is broken

Comment: Seems I can't edit the comment. Github link: <https://github.com/Kitware/CMake/commit/07934636>